# How to deserialize Datum using Lucid

Tags: lucid, inline-datum

The following code allows me to query a Datum from the blockchain using Lucid and Blockfrost:

```typescript
import { Blockfrost, Lucid } from "https://deno.land/x/lucid@0.10.7/mod.ts";

const lucid = await Lucid.new(
  new Blockfrost(
    "https://cardano-preview.blockfrost.io/api/v0",
    <your BLOCKFROST_API_KEY>
  ),
  "Preview"
);

const nft = "b7e0e70f653f23abc39d16f6f6be16fd72e3fe3030db9b16cecccf68524549545f5354415445";  // example

const utxo = await lucid.utxoByUnit(nft);
const datum = utxo.datum
console.log(datum);
```

The output to the console, for this example, is:

```
d8799f1903e819f80c1903e81903e8ff
```

My question now is, what command in Lucid allows me to deserialize this output?  I don't even know what kind of encoding I am dealing with (I suspect it is CBOR).

By the way, I know that the desired deserialization, for this example, should be:

```
{
   constructor: 0,
   fields: [
      {
         int: 1000
      },
      {
         int: 63500
      },
      {
         int: 1000
      },
      {
         int: 1000
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the Lucid command that does the trick is `Data.from`.  First, in the original code, I need to add `Data` in the list of imports:

```typescript
import { Blockfrost, Lucid, Data, } from "https://deno.land/x/lucid@0.10.7/mod.ts";
```

Then simply add:

```typescript
const solution = Data.from(datum);
console.log(solution);
```

at the end of the original code.

Comment: Still it would be nice to know if it is indeed CBOR the encoding from which `Data.from` deserializes.